# Why does React Hooks Axios API call return twice?

Tags: reactjs, axios

Why does React Hooks Axios API Call return twice.. even with a check if it's loaded?

I am used to this.setState but trying to understand the reason behind this why it's showing up twice inside my console log.

My code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const App = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState({ results: [] });
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setIsLoading(true);

      await axios
        .get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
        .then(result => setUsers(result));

      setIsLoading(false);
    };

    fetchData();
  }, []);

  console.log(
    users.status === 200 && users.data.map(name => console.log(name))
  );

  return <h2>App</h2>;
};

export default App;
```

Comment: that's normal behaviour and apart of that, if you use async and await you don't have to use .then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually normal behavior. This is just how functional components work with useEffect(). In a class component the "this" keyword is mutated when the state changes. In functional components with hooks the function is called again, and each function has its own state. Since you updated state twice the function was called twice.

You can read these 2 very in dept articles by one of the creators of react hooks for more details.

https://overreacted.io/a-complete-guide-to-useeffect/

https://overreacted.io/how-are-function-components-different-from-classes/

Answer (score 3):

For the fire twice, perhaps is one time from componentDidMount, and the other one from componentDidUpdate

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

> Does useEffect run after every render? Yes! By default, it runs both after the first render and after every update. (We will later talk about how to customize this.) Instead of thinking in terms of “mounting” and “updating”, you might find it easier to think that effects happen “after render”. React guarantees the DOM has been updated by the time it runs the effects.

You did not check 'isLoading' before you fire the API call

```
    // Only load when is not loading
    if (!isLoading) {
        fetchData();
    }
```

Comment: I'd like to add that, that's why is better to have class-components for this use-cases rather than function-components. Function-components are not meant to deal with data calculations, and that sort of things, function-components are just components that render basic things. For this, you would need some kind of checks, which you could do in any other hook-methods.

Comment: @Omar so basically.. using the old Class based functions and setState and the normal state is better?

Comment: @Galanthus what do you mean by "old class based functions"?

Comment: Since OP has passed empty dependency array into useEffect, the effect is supposed to run only once (in componentDidMount phase)

Comment: I've done the same @Yongzhi and same result. It runs twice. Doing my head in, really.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had a similar issue. in my case `useEffect()` was called twice because the parent component was re-rendered because of a data change.

Comment: `useEffect` is only called twice (or multiple times), if its dependencies change. With dependencies set to `[ ]`, it will only be called once.

Comment: This is almost a valid answer. @Felix is correct that it will only be called once when the dependencies array is empty as it will be called on mount, however if the component was to un-mount and then mount again as a new instance the hook will of course run again. It is important to remember remounting is not the same as re-rendering.